# Online expansion PERC700 RAID6 server

Tags: dell-poweredge, megaraid, raid6, dell-perc

I have a Dell PowerEdge r510, with 5 HDDs in a RAID6 configuration.  I'd like to add a 6th disk (and, in the future, more) to grow the hardware RAID configuration.  I have a logical volume, in which the current disks are all physical volumes.  I have MegaRAID command tools, but cannot see a way to expand the RAID volume without the storage manager software (which I don't have): http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/manuals/0000/860-0488-001/pdf/860-0488-001.pdf.  Can anyone tell me if there is a way to expand the hardware raid volume with MegaRAID or otherwise online (and without reboot if possible)?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure, and I wouldn't try it with my data to find out, but I *think* the `-LDRecon` command shown in 3.10.7 of that document is intended to do this (`-LDRecon -Start –Add PhysDrv[E0:S0,E1:S1....] -Lx -aN`).  It doesn't say if this works on a live array or if you'll lose all your data, so I'd say that you'll need a backup, a boot disk, and plenty of scheduled downtime (or a spare R510 to try it on first)

Comment: I'm running Scientific Linux 6.  DerfK was correct with the LDRecon command (although I had to specify a RAID level, which seems odd when adding and not reconfiguring).  The process has completed, megaraid sees the disk, but parted -l and pvdisplay both show 9TB partitions ... trying to work out how to get the logical volume to recognise the expanded storage now!